# what are the things should not be done inside oncreate() in android?

Tags: android-asynctask, android

My android app will take some time to display my splash screen.It displays black screen for long time.i have created 2 Background threads to do long running process like BD access,network checking,downloading data..etc.but i have to initiated some UI related things in my onCreate.I have no idea about what should i really initiate in UI thread and what should be declared in Background thread as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following, in your onCreate(), make suer you have setContentView() on the top which sets your xml containing the Splash details. Start your background threads and follow it with your UI related loading. But make sure setContentView() is on the top!